# How to Import Wildcard SSL from IIS to Tomcat?

Tags: iis-7

I bought a wildcard ssl from Comodo and created the CSR with one of our IIS7 web servers, but now I have been tasked with installing it on a Tomcat server which is not using the Native APR instead running on Java (JSSE). I know I have to create a JKS file with my keystore using the keytool command, but doesn't that just force me to create a new CSR? How can I import the .pfx file into Tomcat with the keytool command?

Answer (score 0):

This source may help you to import the .pfx file into Tomcat - http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201203.mbox/%3C25624903.96.1332766032984.JavaMail.daniel@cleveland%3E